# How can I prevent ceiling stress cracks from coming back?

Tags: ceiling

I have ceiling stress cracks in my dining/living room ceiling, and it's coming time I tried to fix them.  I went into the attic and noticed the ridge from the garage that runs into the attic has no post, and there are 3-4 interior gable studs missing on one side too.  Can this be causing the cracks to keep coming back?  Before I rip down the sheet rock from the ceiling and replace it, (I've tried to fill the cracks 3 times already and they come back quick and I think from opening them each time with the knife has compromised the integrity already) should I post and put in those gable studs?  Or will it cause extra pressure pushing down on the ceiling?  HELP!!

Comment: How are you fixing them?  Do you have pictures?

Comment: I'll try to get a picture, but up in the attic where the garage roof ridge is there's no post under it where it ends and that seems right over the affected area and there's some studs out too.  I'm going to try to post that ridge, fill in the missing studs, and replace the section of sheet rock in the ceiling under it.  I'm just not sure if that's what I should do, or if some other guys have had this similar problem and recommend it.

Comment: So you have two pieces of sheetrock ending and there is nothing to support them?

Comment: No, the ceiling is where the two horizontal cracks are and there's one little vertical one where the den meets the dining room.  I think the roof is pushing down and the pressure is what's causing the cracks.  There are a couple of cracked rafters up there too, not too bad.  We got the house last year and it's 50 yrs old.  I think they had a lot of weight up there maybe too.

Comment: Cracked rafters is a totally different story.  Please take some pictures.  This sounds more serious than drywall repair.

Comment: Okay, I will, er... I'll try I'm not too technically proficient. And thanks.